# Generating a Quick View of products as modal element in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express-handlebars

I want to generate a quick view of products as a modal element using node.js. I'm passing all the products, i.e `products1` and `products2` fetched from database to render in my index.hbs file. Here is the route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var messages = req.flash('success');
  Product.find((err, docs)=>{
    res.render('index', {title: 'Bookbytes', products1: docs, products2: docs, messages: messages});
    }) 
  })
```

Heres the snippet of the index.hbs file

```
<div class="row furniture--4 arrows_style owl-carousel owl-theme row mt--0">
                        {{# each products1}}
                         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                          <div class="product-grid">
                            <div class="product-image">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="pic-1" src="{{update this.image_path}}" alt="image">
                                </a>
                            <span class="product-discount-label">-50%</span>
                            </div>
                        <div class="product-content">
                            <h3 class="title">
                                <a href="#">{{ this.book_name }}</a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="price">Rs. {{ this.price }}
                                <span> Rs. {{ markedPrice this.price}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li><a href="#" data-tip="Quick View" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="" data-tip="Wishlist" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal" title="Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/add-to-cart/{{ this._id }}" data-tip="Add to cart" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>  
                         </div> 
                    {{/each}} 
               </div>
```

Now I want to generate a modal of that product when which client clicks the anchor tag of quick view. I'm new to node.js. So any suggestions or idea?